# Permissions google-app-javascript in googlesheets: delete pop-up "this site is not safe"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am not an expert in this matter.

I need to know how to certificate my projects of google app script from Googleshhets. So that when I share them with my colleagues, they don´t see a pop-up warning that the "site is not safe" when they execute some script in the sheets.

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in this [help article from Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification) to verify any app that requires user authentication.

Comment: If you are writing code that does not access 3rd party things, including `/* @OnlyCurrentDoc */` at the start of your apps script project will remove the "unsafe" portion.

Comment: @tehhowch It´s works, thanks you very much!!